# Grails not starting the VMWare server

Tags: grails, ports, ggts

I have a project in Groovy Grails Tool Suite. Here are the settings of my **VMWare server**:

```
bio.http.port = 8080
bio.https.port = 8444
```

**Config.groovy**:

```
development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }
```

When I do:

*dev run-app* I get the following in my Console

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security CAS ...
... finished configuring Spring Security CAS

**** ENVIRONMENT ****
***** development****
*********************
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/appName
```

But the VMWare VFabric tc Server tb shows that the server is Stopeed. Actually, if I hit the previous URL nothing happens. Why the console is showing that "Server running" when it is not?

If I right-click my project > Run as > run on server > VMWare

Then I can see the server Started, Syncronized and:
http://localhost:8080/
shows:
*Congratulations! You have successfully setup and started vFabric tc Server Developer Edition. You are ready to go!*

But my applications does not run at all:
http://localhost:8080/appName/

```
HTTP Status 404. The requested resource is not available
```

Any ideas or tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Always put Grails version.  Grails 2 and 3 are very different.

Comment: @Arjang it's in the question already `Loading Grails 2.1.4`

Comment: Are you sure that is not a firewall issue? Try to use wget or curl in the server itself. Just an idea